# Access VBA set form column visibility from other table without hard coding

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My question is related to following tables and form. image3 and image4 are same form, which loads data from Table_2(image2). Table_Setting(image1) is used to define which attribute column should be visible in the SubForm of MainForm (image3 and image 4). That means whether the columns in the subform is visible is defined by user in Table_Setting(image1). For example, according to Table_Setting, if the BookType in MainForm is "novel", then SubForm should display Author,Publisher,BookName; if the BookType is "text book", only display Publisher,PublishYear.

**image1:** 
[image]
**image2:** 
[image]
**image3:** 
[image]
**image4:** 
[image]

I know the following codes can set whether the column in the SubForm is visible or not. But this is hard code version. It is not flexible enough if the user updates the Table_Setting table.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Select Case Forms![SubForm]!BookType
        Case "novel"
            Me.BookType.Visible = True
            Me.Author.Visible = True
            Me.Publisher.Visible = True
            Me.BookName.Visible = True
            Me.PublishYear.Visible = False
        Case "research"
            Me.BookType.Visible = True
            Me.Author.Visible = False
            Me.Publisher.Visible = False
            Me.BookName.Visible = False
            Me.PublishYear.Visible = True           
        Case "text book"    
            Me.BookType.Visible = True
            Me.Author.Visible = Falss
            Me.Publisher.Visible = True
            Me.BookName.Visible = False
            Me.PublishYear.Visible = True                   
    End Select
End Sub
```

**My question:** 
My quesiton is: is it possible to write some codes to automatically set the column visibility simply according to the Table_Setting table while no need to hard code for each column in SubForm? So the user can easily change which columns to display by udating the Table_Setting table only. Thanks a lot.

**Update1:** 
I run the following codes in MainForm.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim strBookType As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strBookType = Me.BookType

    ' Set visible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType = '" & strBookType & "'"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Me!Table_2_DataSheet.Form.Controls(RST!Attribute).Visible = True 'Table_2_DataSheet is the subform name
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    ' Set invisible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Attribute) FROM Table_Setting WHERE Attribute NOT IN (SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType='" & strBookType & "')"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Me!Table_2_DataSheet.Form.Controls(RST!Attribute).Visible = False 'Table_2_DataSheet is the subform name
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    Set RST = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update2:** 
I run the following codes in SubForm.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim strBookType As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strBookType = Me.Parent.BookType

    ' Set visible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType = '" & strBookType & "'"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Me.Controls(RST!Attribute).Visible = True
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    ' Set invisible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Attribute) FROM Table_Setting WHERE Attribute NOT IN (SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType='" & strBookType & "')"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Me.Controls(RST!Attribute).Visible = False
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    Set RST = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following approach

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim RST As Recordset
    Dim strBookType As String
    Dim strSQL as string
    Dim ctrl As Control

    strBookType = Forms![SubForm]!BookType

    ' Set visible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType='" & strBookType & "'"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Set ctrl = Me.Controls(RST!Attribute)
            ctrl.ColumnHidden = False
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    ' Set invisible controls
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Attribute) FROM Table_Setting WHERE Attribute NOT IN (SELECT Attribute FROM Table_Setting WHERE BookType='" & strBookType & "')"
    Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not RST.BOF Then
        While Not RST.EOF
            Set ctrl = Me.Controls(RST!Attribute)
            ctrl.ColumnHidden = True
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    RST.Close

    Set RST = Nothing


End Sub
```

The idea is to retrieve the attributes, to loop on them, and to set visible or not the controls on your form having the attribute's name using `Me.Controls(attribute).ColumnHidden`

---

**Edit:**

At first glance I did not realized that you were trying to hide columns in a datasheet. You can't use the `Visible` property for this, you have to use `ColumnHidden`. I adapted my code accordingly

Comment: thanks a lot for providing the inspiring idea. I tried your approach and put the codes in both MainFom and SubForm, but SubForm still loads all column (without any error message), I have put the codes in the bottom of my question, udpate1 and update2, appreicate if you or someone can provide hints. Thanks again.

Comment: it works!! The codes are truely amazing!! Thanks a lot!